# Ebook Page flipper in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for an e-book reader/displayer similar to the technology used at flashpage (http://www.flashpageflip.com/Online-Demo.asp) but in Javascript?

Any ideas/links much appriciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- http://lab.smashup.it/flip/
- http://jonraasch.com/blog/quickflip-2-jquery-plugin
- http://www.jquery.info/scripts/jFlip/demo.html
- http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-sprite-animation-using-jquery/